# Double view push fix broken with dynamic loading views

Tags: sencha-touch-2, push

I am using ST2.2 and have applied a fix that caused two views to be pushed when the user tapped a button, list item etc twice. Here is the fix:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.NavView', {
   extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',

   push: function (view) {
      if(this.getActiveItem().xtype != view.xtype)
         this.callParent(arguments);
      else
         console.warn("Prevented pushing a potentially duplicate view of xtype: " + view.xtype);
   }
});
```

This worked great, when I had all the views declared in app.js which were initilaized at launch. Since then, in order to improve performance and reduce the DOM size, I have switched all views to be loaded dynamically. Anotherwords, only the main view is not included in views in app.js. The other views are initialized and pushed as needed.

The fix above no longer works and I am back to the original problem.

I have also tried including MyApp.view.NavView to requires: for the application in app.js without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add mutex on button to prevent double tap handler:

```
//somewhere in controller
tapNextButton: function(btn)
{
    if (btn.mutex) return;
    btn.mutex = true;
    setTimeout(function() {btn.mutex = false;}, TAP_BUFFER_LONG);
            // push new screen here
},
```

Or you can use "buffer" property for tap listener in button definition
or override: 'Ext.event.recognizer.SingleTouch' whole project